# Reinstalling my XAMPP, I only copied a folder in xmapp>mysql>data my database

Tags: mysql, xampp

Inside this database are .frm, .ibd files and db.opt, that's all i got. Is there a way possible to recover all the data in my database? I don't have my original ibdata file, ib_logfile0 and ib_logfile1, and I don't have any .MYD and MYI.

Comment: Depends on your database format & version. If it is innoDB with barracuda, you might be able to recover it:
Install a new mysql, create a database, copy the files in there and see after a restart of mysql if it wants to recover them. It might be needed to create the tables first and then overwrite them with your backup.

Comment: Thank you for the quick respond. I'm using xampp version V3.2.1, how can you tell if your database is innoDB with barracuda? At this point I'm confused. Thanks again

Comment: I did what you told @Nobert but it gives me an error that says "Table 'sample_table' doesn't exist".

Comment: Can you create 'sample_table' (create table sample_table) with all correct columns, and then replace the MYD and MYI file?

Answer (score 0):

At first take backup. Then delete/Drop database from PHPMYADMIN. Then import from *.sql file. Otherwise you found db name only but not tables.Do you take backup with export from PHPMyADMIN or SQLBUDDY?